# Python os.linkdir

Tags: python, file, directory

```
 import os
 path = "D:\uda\prank\photo"
 def rename_files():
     print os.path.exists(path)
     if os.path.exists(path):
         print("exists")
         file_list = os.listdir(path)
         print(file_list)
     else:
         print("No luck")
```

I'm trying to print a list of filenames using os.listdir method, however nothing appeared even from "exists" or "No luck", so what could be happening over here? I thought it was because of administrator's restriction, however now I'm pretty sure that won't bother at all. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a function (`rename_files`), but never call it (at least from the posted code).

Comment: Oh it was so obvious! I've learned python for years it's just I'm starting to build wheels and found that there's so many things I haven't been aware of. Little things like this. Thank you again for this fast response.